# What do I have to drag and to where in order to dismiss a keyboard with a tap on the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm writing an app in which I want to dismiss the keyboard by clicking in the background.  I know I need to type in the following code somewhere **after** dragging one of the "Sent Events" dots to somewhere on the view controller.  Assume for this example that the text field is called textField.

`-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}`

Which dot do I need to drag from in "Sent Events" and to where?  I know that this is the code that will work, but I can never remember which dot to use and where to drop it on the screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I remember it now.

I need to use Touch Down with a type of `id` and call it `backgroundTap`.  Thanks, myself.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I need to resign first responder in the event of a background tap, I overwrite the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` UIViewController method, and in there, I resign first responders. I'm not sure if this is possible using Interface Builder in one quick action.

Comment: I know that it is possible in Interface Builder because I've done it before, but I can't ever remember which one to use, so I have to look it up each time.  I'm on vacation right now and don't have access to the book.

Answer (score 1):

Use button in background to click out..and write simple code for click EVENT TOUCH UP INSIDE

```
-(IBAction)backgroundbuttonpress:(id)sender 

{

 [textField resignFirstResponder]; 

}
```

connect action to button...and make sure that You have declared `UITextFieldDelegate` in .H file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a UIGestureRecognizer to you background view. Like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do whatever you want...

    UITapGestureRecognizer *screenTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                           action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    screenTapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:screenTapped];

}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Now the keyboard will be dismissed when the user taps the background view.

Hope it helps!